# How to auto scroll MPAndroidChart line chart?

Tags: android, android-graphview, mpandroidchart

I am new user of [**MPAndroidChart**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) in android. 
can any one help me ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "auto-scroll"?

Comment: Thanks for reply,i want graph like stock graph. continues update in graph with scroll.

Comment: I dont fully understand. Could you explain in detail what it is you want to do?

Comment: Sorry for explanation, I am building app in which i want to show 10  point in line graph for ex. 1,2,---10. when i add 11th point in line graph my 1 point should be removed form graph but not removed form LineData.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So what you want to do is always show 10 values in the chart, regardless of how many values are stored in the `LineData` object?

You can do that by restraining the view on the horizontal (x) axis and then aim the view at the data you want to be visible. Therefore, you need to call

`setScaleMinima((float) lineData.getXValCount() / 10f, 1f)`

This will restrain the view on the x-axis and always show exactly 10 values. Then you can set where your view should aim at by calling

`centerViewPort(float val, int xindex)`

If you call centerViewPort(500f, 11), your view will be aimed at the y-value 500 (vertical axis) and on the 11th value on the horizontal (x) axis.

Please let me know if this helped you.

**UPDATE**:

In newer versions of the library above 2.0.0, please refer the [**wiki**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport) on how to modify the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One problem I have is the chart increasingly zooms. That means as I add more Entry, the chart display less and less points. Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: `chart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(minBarsToShow)` should work as well, it's essentially `chart.setViewPortHandler().setMaximumScaleY(maxBars/minBarsToShow);` Just do it for the Max as well and you'll lock it.

Comment: `chart.moveViewToX(0);` just do nothing for me, after reseting BarData

Comment: In newer version of library, i.e 3.0.1 how can we put labels to x coordinates instead of showing the x value